# Why do I get Invalid Request when uploading file using fckeditor file browse?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, fckeditor

I.m using FCKEditor(2.6.6) in an asp.net 2.0 project Using the upload tab on the link dialog, I get alertbox with 'Invalid Request'. yet when I use the resource browser to upload a file; It succeed.

What the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well. The problem is that it can't find the type of resource for upload. I assume that it should detect the resource type by file extension, but there is no code to do that.

I fixed it by adding the resource type "File" in the config. I think this is a workaround, but it worked for me.

So the link browser url looks somewhat like this (added Type=File&):
FCKConfig.LinkBrowserURL = FCKConfig.BasePath + 'filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=File&Connector=../../../../connector.' + _FileBrowserExtension;

And the quick upload looks like this (added + '?Type=File' ):
FCKConfig.LinkUploadURL = FCKConfig.BasePath + '../upload.' + _QuickUploadExtension + '?Type=File' ;